# How to prevent direct access to images in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need the same thing as this guy here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1507682.aspx

The thing is that the answer he marked as correct doesn't work for me. I am using ASP.NET MVC3 soon to be migrated to MVC4 and Windows Server 2012.
I want to prevent direct access to some images because of security issues. It's not Image Leeching protection I'm worried at this moment, I read several articles on how to do that.

If the link is on my page like this

```
<img src="/Content/Images/img1.jpg" />
```

The image should be shown, but not if it is directly accessed:

```
http://mywebsite.com/Content/Images/img1.jpg
```

Since we're talking about images and several people accessing it, a solution that considers performance issue would be my way to go.

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to think outside MVC and [handle hotlinking in IIS itself](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/prevent_hotlinking_url_rewrite.htm).  IIS has the tools (the referer (sic) header) to figure out whether or not an image request appears to have come from inside your site or not.

Comment: That is a very good idea, since I have full control over my server. This will make the access work the way I described, right? Thanks for you answer, I'll try this later.

Comment: @eestein it will prevent hotlinking (search engine results or a 3rd party website linking directly to your images).  If you have genuine security concerns about a file, best to not put it on a public website in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually a gray area and for the moment I have no option. :D

Answer (score 3):

Write an Action method which reads the image from disk / db and render it. In that action method, you may check whether the user is authorized or not and return the appropriate image or a "not authorized" image.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Photo(string id)
  {
   // TO DO:  get image using the unique id passed and render it
  }
}
```

You can use the path to this action method as your image path.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Photo","Product")/someUniqueIDOfPhotoFromYourDB" />
```

This approach will have a slight performance impact compared to serving image directly from disk.

Comment: Is that the best way? I really didn't want to delay the process more. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Probably since you state that you want to control from where (uri) the resource is accessed.

Comment: @Romoku Ok, but I'm not using DB to store my images. And that's not in my plan as well. Can that be done using a local file? As I see from his answer I would need to change the permissions of the images to avoid this direct access, right? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible with Local files as well. You can use `Image.FromFile` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx

Comment: It doesn't matter where the images are located. You can just relay the image off the disk and deny viewing permission to the directory in the web.config.

Comment: @Shyju Thanks, for that to work I would have to remove permissions for those images, right?